# library not found for -lPods-test clang when compiling unit tests

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, cocoapods

I am trying to run my unit tests and I get the below error:

```
    ld: library not found for -lPods-test clang: error: 
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)  

Ld /Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYIOSPROJProjectTests.xctest/MYIOSPROJProjectTests normal i386
    cd /Users/AUSER/Documents/Dev/MYIOSPROJProject/MYIOSPROJProject
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Intermediates/MYIOSPROJProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYIOSPROJProjectTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/MYIOSPROJProjectTests.LinkFileList -bundle_loader /Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYIOSPROJProject.app/MYIOSPROJProject -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework XCTest -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods-test -lPods-MYIOSPROJProjectTests -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Intermediates/MYIOSPROJProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYIOSPROJProjectTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/MYIOSPROJProjectTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYIOSPROJProjectTests.xctest/MYIOSPROJProjectTests
```

As someone who is new to IOS I legitimately have no idea where to even start. Any guidance would be appreciated (please be detailed as I am new).

Pod File:

```
platform :ios, 6.0
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0rc'

# Include optional Testing and Search components
pod 'RestKit/Testing', '~> 0.20.0rc'
pod 'RestKit/Search', '~> 0.20.0rc'


target :IOSProjectTests do
  pod 'Expecta',     '~> 0.2.3'   # expecta matchers
  # pod 'Specta',      '~> 0.1.11'  # specta bdd framework
end
```

Comment: Is your podspec specifying that certain pods should be exclusive to your test target?

Comment: @JonReid Added pod file above, I believe it is.

Comment: While I see issues in the Podfile, I was able to use it as-is in a new project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deleted the -lPods-test file that was in the project and this fixed the issue.

This can be found in the `Frameworks` directory in the folder nav area

Comment: Just to clarify: I deleted an extraneous pod library found under Pods > Products in the xcode workspace navigator.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue multiple times the past few days and have been able to fix it each time by doing a `CMD-SHIFT-OPTION-K` clean and in terminal rerunning `pod install` in my project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Xcode resolved this issue for me. (Worth a shot before doing anything more involved.)